# Summing pairs of elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to write a function that returns a list of all different pairs of numbers which add up to 10. For example for `{1,9,3,7,8}` the function should return `{{1,9},{9,1},{3,7},{7,3}}`.

I found out how to do it without a function but for some reasons when I add the function to it, it stops working.

Here is my code without the function:

```
Select[Permutations[{1, 9, 3, 7, 8}, {2}], Total@# == 10 &];
```

And here is the code with the function that returns no result:

```
fun[listY_] := Select[Permutations[{listY}, {2}], Total@# == 10 &]

fun[{1, 9, 3, 7, 8}]
```

Do you know what could be the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks almost like [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192512).

Comment: Right I am trying to do sth similar to that question but I have to add a function to it

Comment: Study the difference between `Permutations[listY]` and `Permutations[{listY}]`, in fact, study the difference between `listY` and `{listY}`.